# Pass values between PHP files called by SH script

Tags: php, sh

i'm trying to call a PHP script from a SH script.
It's easy, i receive the values from SH, but nothing is passed when i try to pass values from first PHP to other PHP using OOP.

Here's the first PHP, it receive a simple call from a SH file than pass values by URL:

```
$controller = $_GET['c'];
$metodo     = $_GET['m'];
$uniqueid       = $_GET['uniqueid'];

$url = '../controllers/'.ucfirst($controller).'.controller.php';

include_once($url);

$controller = ucfirst($controller)."Controller";

$objeto = new $controller;
$dados = $_POST;

$objeto->dados = $dados;

$objeto->uniqueid = $uniqueid;

//CALL THE FUNCTION
$result = $objeto->$metodo($uniqueid);

//RETURN THE RESPONSE
echo  $result;
```

And here i receive values passed to object:
(Here's the problem, the values are empty)

```
include('../classes/Tarifacao.class.php');
class TarifacaoController{
    public function Tarifa($uniqueid){
        $obj_tarif = new Tarifacao;
        $bilhete = $obj_tarif->BuscaUltimoBilhete($uniqueid);
        echo $this->Imprime($bilhete,'BILHETE');

        $uniqueid = $bilhete['uniqueid'];
        echo $this->Imprime($uniqueid,'UNIQUEID');

        intval($duracao = $bilhete['billsec']);
        echo $this->Imprime($duracao,'DURAÇÃO');
        ...
```

Sorry, my english is so poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute PHP from the command line, you cannot pass values like that.
You need to use the `$argv` reserved variable: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

You can try something like this:

```
$controller = $argv[1];
$metodo     = $argv[2];
$uniqueid   = $argv[3];
```

And execute the script like this from the shell:

```
$ php script.php <c> <m> <uniqueid>
```